# Android webview content offset

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to display semi-transparent view at the top of screen (some kind of toolbar) and a webview below it. This toolbar should not overlap content of the webview (so after first launch webview is located directly below toolbar), but when user scrolls the webview, part of the webview content should be visible under toolbar.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
BTW, I didn't find any way to achieve this using native View/ScrollView methods, so I used following javascript:

```
$('body').css('padding-top','50px');
```